# Why property is not sets on model in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I try to save model with ref to the different model named class. And property is in model after i create it but when i save it class is disappear.

It is code of saving

```
const newStudent = class_id ? new _Student({vkId, class: class_id}) : new _Student({vkId});
//newStudent have class property 
await newStudent.save();//but there it is dissapear
return await DataBase.getStudentBy_Id(newStudent._id);
```

class_id is objectId from document

It is how i define class property in schema

```
class: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: "Class",
        autopopulate: true
    }
```

Help pls.

Comment: Please, can you share the full `Student` schema? Also, you can try setting mongoose debug option to true(`mongoose.set('debug', true)`) and inspect the actual query the `await newStudent.save()` generates in the terminal.

Comment: It is a Student model

`{
    class: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: "Class",
        autopopulate: true
    },
    role: {
        type: String,
        default: Roles.student,
        validate: {
            validator: (role) => Roles[role],
            message: "Role must be one of defined"
        }
    },
    vkId: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    isSubscribedToMailing: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
    }
}`

Comment: And it is a debug log
`Mongoose: students.createIndex({ vkId: 1 }, { unique: true, background: true })`
`Mongoose: students.insertOne({ role: 'STUDENT', isSubscribedToMailing: true, _id: ObjectId("5e5e44b66f212b1c60fb33a6"), vkId: 29, class: ObjectId("5e5e43f71c9d4400007f8be1"), __v: 0}, { session: null })`
`Mongoose: classes.createIndex({ name: 1 }, { unique: true, background: true })`
`Mongoose: classes.find({ _id: { '$in': [ ObjectId("5e5e43f71c9d4400007f8be1") ] } }, { skip: undefined, limit: undefined, perDocumentLimit: undefined, maxDepth: 10, _depth: 1, projection: {}})`

Comment: `Mongoose: students.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("5e5e44b66f212b1c60fb33a6") }, { projection: {} })`
`Mongoose: classes.find({ _id: { '$in': [ ObjectId("5e5e43f71c9d4400007f8be1") ] } }, { skip: undefined, limit: undefined, perDocumentLimit: undefined, maxDepth: 10, _depth: 1, projection: {}})`

Comment: By `disappear`, you mean the `student.class` property has a `null` value right?

Comment: Yes, it is true

Comment: Ok. The problem is that the class id you saved in the student document(`5e5e43f71c9d4400007f8be1`) does not reference a valid class document. The `autopopulate: true` property you specified on `Student.class` schema would make mongoose to always attempt to load the referenced document from its collection(`Class`) and since the document does not exist in this case, the result would be `null`. Just to confirm, can you try querying for a class document with _id of `5e5e43f71c9d4400007f8be1`, do you get a result?

Comment: Aahh, okay i think i realised what is wrong, when i create student with class._id i didn`t saved class yet and because of it it returns null.
P.S Already fixed it
P.P.S Thank you very much <3 <3 <3